# No displaying the score on the last ScoreViewController Swift

Tags: swift, label, segue, viewcontroller

Im having trouble with my segue function, Im trying to pass the final score to the second view but is not displaying on the label this is what i have for my segue function:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destinationScore : ScoreViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ScoreViewController

    destinationScore.scoreBoard?.text = String(finalScore)
    NSLog(String(finalScore))
}
```

Here is the second view controller.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreBoard: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}
```

PS: My NSLog is displaying the final score on the terminal but not on the label. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When prepareForSegue performed, the contents (including view and subviews) of ScoreViewController haven't been loaded yet. So the scoreBoard label was nil when you set the value for label. Therefore the scoreBoard label can't show your score.

To resolve this problem:

- You'd better add property `var score: String` in ScoreViewController, then assign text for label in `viewDidLoad` function.
- In prepareForSegue, assign score property instead of scoreBoard label.

Comment: its working now!! thank you... so beside send the data direct to the label its better to store in a var and display it in the viewDidLoad?